# Cannot use html tags inside popover

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code,my problem is when i tried to add  or any other html tag inside it as shown its not working and it displayed as normal string.

```
<%= link_to image_tag(class_door(student_class), onMouseover: "this.src='/assets/open_door.png';", onMouseout: "this.src='/assets/closed_door.png'" ),'javascript:;' ,class:'popovers','data-content'=>"Number of Students: #{student_class.students.count}<br><button>Click to enter</button>" ,'data-original-title'=>"#{student_class.name.capitalize}" %>
```

also i have tried to add html_safe to be like this

```
<%= link_to image_tag(class_door(student_class), onMouseover: "this.src='/assets/open_door.png';", onMouseout: "this.src='/assets/closed_door.png'" ),'javascript:;' ,class:'popovers','data-content'=>"Number of Students: #{student_class.students.count}<br><button>Click to enter</button>".html_safe ,'data-original-title'=>"#{student_class.name.capitalize}" %>
```

but this also wasn't working and giving the same result

Comment: Do you have your popover code for us to see?

Comment: well , i am using an external theme which based on bootstrap 3 , i guess this is for popovers

`var handlePopovers = function () {
        jQuery('.popovers').popover();

        // close last poped popover

        $(document).on('click.popover.data-api',function(e) {
            if(lastPopedPopover){
                lastPopedPopover.popover('hide');
            } 
        });
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `'data-html'=>true`.  You'd want something like:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(class_door(student_class), onMouseover: "this.src='/assets/open_door.png';", onMouseout: "this.src='/assets/closed_door.png'" ),'javascript:;' ,class:'popovers', 'data-html'=>true, 'data-content'=>"Number of Students: #{student_class.students.count}<br><button>Click to enter</button>" ,'data-original-title'=>"#{student_class.name.capitalize}" %>
```

And if any of the values you are putting into your HTML need to be escaped to prevent injection, you can use "h".  Something like: `#{h(student_class.name.capitalize)}`.